# Extracting values from a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following string which i would like to retrieve some values from:

```
============================
Control 127232:
map #;-
============================
Control 127235:
map $;NULL
============================
Control 127236:
```

I want to take only the Control . Hence is there a way to retrieve from that string above into an array containing like `[127232, 127235, 127236]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (assuming your string is named s and each line is made with \n):

```
List<string> ret = new List<string>();
foreach (string t in s.Split('\n').Where(p => p.StartsWith("Control")))
    ret.Add(t.Replace("Control ", "").Replace(":", ""));
```

`ret.Add(...)` part is not elegant, but works...

**EDITED:**
If you want an array use `string[] arr = ret.ToArray();`

**SYNOPSYS:**
I see you're really a newbie, so I try to explain:

- `s.Split('\n')` creates a string[] (every line in your string)
- `.Where(...)` part extracts from the array only strings starting with Control
- `foreach` part navigates through returned array taking one string at a time
- `t.Replace(..)` cuts unwanted string out
- `ret.Add(...)` finally adds searched items into returning list

Comment: hmm this doesnt store into a variable?

Comment: @user866800: yes, into `List<string> ret`. If you want an array take a look at my edited post.

Answer (score 3):

One way of achieving this is with regular expressions, which does introduce some complexity but will give the answer you want with a little LINQ for good measure.

Start with a regular expression to capture, within a group, the data you want:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Control\s+(\d+):");
```

This will look for the literal string "Control" followed by one or more whitespace characters, followed by one or more numbers (within a capture group) followed by a literal string ":".

Then capture matches from your input using the regular expression defined above:

```
var matches = regex.Matches(inputString);
```

Then, using a bit of LINQ you can turn this to an array

```
var arr = matches.OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(m => long.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value))
                 .ToArray();
```

now `arr` is an array of `long`'s containing just the numbers.

Live example here: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=ZCMH97137

Comment: i'm sorry this appears too complex to me :(

Comment: @user - then you need to start with a simpler problem, and perhaps a beginner book on C#.

Comment: @user866800 read about LINQ and regular expressions. Both are just things one needs learning about. Both powerful and helpful, guaranteed to save you time and effort in long run.

Comment: @user - what specifically is too complex for you? Regular expressions are pretty complex but i've handed you the answer to this one. LINQ's various methods are just a case of reading the docs. Perhaps if something isnt clear in my post I can expand it a little bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head try this (it's quick and dirty), assuming the text you want to search is in the variable 'text':

```
        List<string> numbers = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(text, "[^\\d+]").ToList();
        numbers.RemoveAll(item => item == "");
```

The first line splits out all the numbers into separate items in a list, it also splits out lots of empty strings, the second line removes the empty strings leaving you with a list of the three numbers. if you want to convert that back to an array just add the following line to the end:

```
        var numberArray = numbers.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way exists. I can't recall a simple way for It, but string is to be parsed for extracting this values. Algorithm of it is next:

1. Find a word "Control" in string and its end
2. Find a group of digits after the word
3. Extract number by int.parse or TryParse
4. If not the end of the string - goto to step one

realizing of this algorithm is almost primitive..)

This is simplest implementation (your string is str):

```
    int i, number, index = 0;        
    while ((index = str.IndexOf(':', index)) != -1)
    {
        i = index - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && char.IsDigit(str[i])) i--;
        if (++i < index)
        {
            number = int.Parse(str.Substring(i, index - i));
            Console.WriteLine("Number: " + number);
        }
        index ++;
    }
```

Using LINQ for such a little operation is doubtful.

Comment: can you demonstrate an example?

Comment: In my opinion code readability and simplicity should trump code optimization in all cases except when one is optimizing. Processing power is cheaper than development time, too.

Comment: As for me, readability of plain simple algorithm with comments is more than in something magic code like that:List<string> ret = new List<string>();
foreach (string t in s.Split('\n').Where(p => p.StartsWith("Control")))
    ret.Add(t.Replace("Control ", "").Replace(":", ""));